# How to protect microcontroler analogue 0-5V input pins from high/negative voltage

Tags: microcontroller, voltage

Just a little background info, I'm designing a small standalone battery powered unit to be developed that will allow the output of a sensor to be displayed on an LCD screen and that the input to the unit will have a 0-5V range from the sensors.

My question is how could I protect the analogue input pins of my microcontroller from high/negative voltages while also being able to display values from sensors that do not have this output range?

EDIT: I am designing this device for others to use and will not know what kind of sensor they would be using, all I'm told is to expect a range of 0-5V and include protection from anything else.

Comment: What you need is an "input voltage clamp circuit", use Google with that and look at the images tab. Also see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229589/is-this-clamping-voltage-divider-for-a-high-impedance-input-a-good-robust-desig

Comment: High? How high? How negative? What is the maximum input current value stated in the data sheet?

Comment: "anything else" is a crummy specification. 230VAC mains? 100kV distribution power? There's going to be a big difference between a protection circuit that works reliably up to 12VDC and one that can withstand even a momentary mains connection and still maintains whatever impedance  (hint, you've not stated it) maximum your analog pins require. Also accuracy needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use clamping diodes to limit the input signal voltage. You can either connect external clamping diodes from input to the +5V line and ground, or use internal clamping diodes that are already built into your microcontroller. 
Make sure to use Schottky diodes, not regular ones.

How does it work: when Vin is higher than Val+, the top limit diode starts conducting, clamping the Vin to Val+ + 0.3V. When Vin is lower than Val-, the lower diode clamps. Current flowing through the diode is limited by the input resistor. 0.3V is the forward drop voltage of Schottky diode.

[image]

If you decide to use internal diodes, make sure the current through them would [not exceed 1mA](https://scienceprog.com/using-current-limiting-resistors-on-avr-io-pins/). This is achieved by increasing the input resistor to about 10㏀, which could degrade you ADC performance, so it would be a good idea to use external clamping diodes that could handle 200mA, and lower resistor value (200Ω to 1㏀).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To clarify, what is meant by Val+ and Val- in your diagram and what are they connected to.

Comment: @House_Byrne these are the maximum and minimum voltage limits for you input pin. In most cases they would be connected to power rail (+5V) and ground, respectively.

Comment: @House_Byrne please also read the link I provided in the answer, it gives more detailed explanation on clamping circuit https://scienceprog.com/using-current-limiting-resistors-on-avr-io-pins/

Comment: I see now, thank you very informative. How would I power the clamping diodes if I were to use it externally?

Comment: For external protection where you don't have a power line available, you have to use Zener/TVS diodes of appropriate breakdown voltage. For example, SA5.0A is a TVS diode rated to hold 5.0V and breakdown somewhere between 6.40 and 7.00V.

Comment: Could I use the 5V and Ground pin in my Arduino as the power line and ground or is that defeating the purpose?

Comment: @House_Byrne Yes, you should use the same power line that's powering your microcontroller. So connect top clamping diode Kathode to +5V of Arduino, and bottom diode Anode to ground of Arduino.